# Why JavaScript cannot properly calculate 9 ** 1/2? The output is 4.5 instead of 3

Tags: javascript, exponentiation

```js
console.log(Math.pow(9, 1 / 2) === 9 ** 1 / 2) // false

console.log(9 ** 1 / 2) // 4.5
```

Comment: Because you want `9 ** (1/2)`, but are doing `(9 ** 1)/2`. Exponentiation has higher operator precedence than division.

Comment: 4.5 is the correct result, if you don't use any parenthesis, to change the precedence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are calculating `Math.pow(9,1) / 2` which is the same as `9/2`

Comment: Correctly, you'd use decimals (0.5) to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of operator precedence. `**` has a higher precedence than `/` in the same way that `*` has higher precedence thatn `+`.

You wouldn't expect `3 * 3 + 2` to equal 15 do you?

So similarly your `9**1 / 2` is interpreted as `(9**1) / 2`. If you mean to raise `9` to the power of `0.5` you need to clarify it as:

```
9 ** (1/2)
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can write this as `9 ** 0.5`, which doesn't run into order-of-operations issues.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is something that people might struggle with, even if you do math with pen and paper. `2x^2 != (2x)^2`

Comment: @CerebralFart That is a neat trick but doesn't help you in real code because in real code you usually have to deal with variables like `1/x` which can't be hardcoded. Teach someone about order of operations and the use of braces and it will solve all his future problems